# Can't convert iPhone heic photo to jpg

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, converters, heif

I'm trying to convert heic to jpg. I use the [official library](https://github.com/nokiatech/heif) on js. The problem is that I can decode a heic photo from the repository (callback returns an array of data), but I can't decode heic photos taken on the iPhone (In this case, the callback doesn't return anything at all).

Has anyone tried to convert a heic photo, that was made on an iPhone to jpg?

```js
var reader = new HEIFReader('test/1.heic');
var decoder = new HevcDecoder();
var imgData = new ImageProvider(reader, decoder);

reader.requestFileInfo(function(payload) {
  if (payload.success !== true) {
    console.error("Could not read file:", url);
  } else {
    var fileInfo = payload;
    console.log("FileInfo contents:", fileInfo);

    if (fileInfo.rootLevelMetaBoxProperties) {
      var masterContextId = fileInfo.rootLevelMetaBoxProperties.contextId;
      var masterItemIds = [];
      var imageFeaturesMap = fileInfo.rootLevelMetaBoxProperties.imageFeaturesMap;

      for (i in imageFeaturesMap) {
        if (imageFeaturesMap.hasOwnProperty(i) && imageFeaturesMap[i].isMasterImage === true) {
          masterItemIds.push(parseInt(i));
        }
      }
      console.log("Master images in the file:", masterItemIds);

      imgData.requestImageData(masterContextId, masterItemIds, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });

    }

  }
});
```

Comment: please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754688/convert-heic-to-jpg-using-php-or-js

Answer (score -1):

I wrote [this python script](https://gist.github.com/urigoren/b8dc1c944d313444a4ba1efc953db003) to convert

A snippet from the script:

```
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
from pillow_heif import register_heif_opener
register_heif_opener()

files = list(Path(".").glob("*.heic")) + list(Path(".").glob("*.HEIC"))

for f in files:
    image = Image.open(str(f))
    image.convert('RGB').save(str(f.with_suffix('.jpg')))
    if params.delete:
        f.unlink()
```