# Converting HEIF to JPG in PHP

Tags: php, image

I have a PHP script to upload an image. The image is then checked to see if it is valid (jpeg/png) and then converted to jpeg if it isn't a jpeg but is a valid image.

Apple now has HEIC filetypes and I'm struggling on how to handle this within in my script as there doesn't appear to be a mimetype for HEIC.

Has anyone found a solution to uploading HEIC and then converting to jpeg using PHP?

Comment: Have you checked whether [your question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754688/convert-heic-to-jpg-using-php-or-js)? And then there's also the [WEBP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp) from Google. I see that more and more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert HEIC to JPG , using php or JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754688/convert-heic-to-jpg-using-php-or-js)